# A number based on which the logarithmic function outputs negative values for proper fractions only?

Tags: logarithms

Let this number be $B$, $B$ achieves the following:

$\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(B)}>0$, for x>1

$\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(B)}<0$, for 1>x>0

If such a number is worth serious attention, what is its name by which I can find more information?

Comment: I'm quite confused after reading your question - not sure exactly what you're saying. Could you rewrite it more clearly?

Comment: Is it the formatting that is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All logarithmic functions with a base greater than one satisfy the description.

$$\log_B{x}=\frac{\log{x}}{\log{B}}$$

For all real values of $B$ and $B>1$, the value of $\log{B}$ is greater than zero and finite.

The function $\log{x}$ is greater than zero for all $x>1$, and negative for all $0<x<1$

This set of output does not change in positivity/negativity by the division of a real, positive denominator, therefore, all real values of $B$ greater than one satisfy the descriptions.